# "clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files" during Swift iOS build

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I just installed an additional dependency (HockeyAppSDK) using CocoaPods for my Swift iOS project and now my project fails during build giving me the error:

> clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files

I uninstalled the dependency and the project still fails during build with the same error. Any ideas on how to fix this?

EDIT: 
When building using the xcode cli the errors looks like:

2015-07-24 20:28:09.378 xcodebuild[34313:1668414] stream error: stream error at offset 29: created by an unsupported XCDependencyGraph build

The following build commands failed:

CompileSwift normal arm64 {Path to swift file}

CompileSwift normal arm64 {Path to swift file}

CompileSwift normal arm64 {Path to swift file}

CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compile

Comment: Whatdoes the command line look like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was a bug in CocoaPods 0.38.1 as [this issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3893) indicates. So this is probably fixed in future versions of CocoaPods.

What you can do to fix the problem temporarily before a new CocoaPods release: the bug is that somewhere in the private xcconfig files, there is missing a space before `-isystem`

**EDIT:**

A new version of Cocoapods [(0.38.2)](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/0.38.2) is released that fixes this issue

Answer (score 3):

[CocoaPods 0.38.2](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/0.38.2) is now released. It fixes the issue.